# How to use Dash and Alfred to search through Ruby Syntax documentation?

Tags: ruby, alfred

I've added the Ruby 2.1.5 Standard library documentation but what I'm wondering is how can I add the [Ruby Syntax](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#break) documentation to Dash as well?

Comment: Why 2.1.5 and not 2.3.0?

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question on this topic and repost it? (Original URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108621/how-to-use-dash-alfred-to-find-examples-of-common-ruby-coding-structures)

Comment: because it's a a related but more specific and ultimately different question that makes the first one not relevant anymore. @tadman ideally I'd like to be able to switch between the syntax for different versions of ruby, the only reason why I'm using 2.1.5 is because I'm working with a group that's using that version of ruby

Answer (score 0):

I just got this response from Bogdan over at Dash,

> Hi,
>
> Ruby Syntax is not currently available in Dash. If more users ask I'll
>   add it. So far you're the first one.
>
> Regards, Bogdan

So it looks like if you're reading this and interested maybe shoot him an email over at support (at) kapeli (dot) com and he may add it to the supported docset